export products from admin panel not working
we are trying to export products from the Magento 2 admin panel. However, the file is not exporting as expected. Occasionally, we notice that the files export automatically at midnight.
We have also configured RabbitMQ, but it has not resolved the issue.
When we run the SSH command:

php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

the file exports successfully, but the command execution gets stuck in SSH.
*RabbitMQ configuration on app/etc/env.php

'queue' => [  'amqp' => [         'host' =>
'cg-32016-rabbitmq.us-midwest-1.nxcli.net',       'port' => '9..1',
'user' => 'rabbitmq',       'password' => 'Ber..dTaps',         'virtualhost'
=> '/'    ],      'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1 ],
'cron_consumers_runner' => [  'cron_run' => true,     'max_messages' =>
20000,    'consumers' => [        'async.operations.all',
'codegeneratorProcessor',       'exportProcessor',
'product_action_attribute.update',
'product_action_attribute.website.update'   ] ],

Cron configuration
/usr/sbin/relax /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin/php /chroot/home/ae6400c0/f073ee7314.nxcli.net/html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /chroot/home/ae6400c0/f073ee7314.nxcli.net/html/var/log/magento.cron.log





 


Please check the magento.cron.log and cron_schedule table.
